# How can i add Dynamic Json data into a Mysql Database.

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, database

How can i add JSON Data into a Database? i have a script there is generating automatic updated JSON Data. i read in a book that i should use a methode called

```
JSON_decode
```

I Think i should have to do something like, put The value into The tables for each value. Then try to use The methode JSON_decode and then make a loop foreach. but i am not sure about this. what is the best way, and can you tell me what to do in my case or maby show a example?

Here is the data located:

http://csgo.nssgaming.com/api.php

The current script:

```
<?php
require_once ('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = @file_get_html('http://csgolounge.com/');
$output = array();

if(!$html) exit(json_encode(array("error" => "Unable to connect to CSGOLounge")));

// Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#86964
function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) {
preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags);
$tags = array_unique($tags[1]);

if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) {
    if($invert == FALSE)
        return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
    else
        return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
} elseif($invert == FALSE) {
    return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
}

return $text;
}

foreach($html->find('.matchmain') as $match) {
$when = $match->find('.whenm')[0];
$status = trim($when->find('span')[0]->plaintext) == "LIVE" ? true : false;
$event = $match->find('.eventm')[0]->plaintext;
$time = trim(strip_tags_content($when->innertext));
$id = substr($match->find('a')[0]->href, 8);
    $additional = substr(trim($when->find('span')[$status ? 1 : 0]->plaintext), 4);
$result;

$output[$id]["live"] = $status;
$output[$id]["time"] = $time;
$output[$id]["event"] = $event;

foreach($match->find('.teamtext') as $key => $team) {
    $output[$id]["teams"][$key] = array(
        "name" => $team->find('b')[0]->plaintext,
        "percent" => $team->find('i')[0]->plaintext
    );

    if(@$team->parent()->find('img')[0])
        $result = array("status" => "won", "team" => $key);
    }

if($additional)
    $result = $additional;

if(isset($result))
    $output[$id]["result"] = $result;
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: You need to save this json data into table as it is (data-type of the column must be long-text). When you fetch this for showing purpose then you need to json_decode it so that it will convert in an array and then use it as you want?

Comment: Yes something i just want to save the data into a database but can you make a simpel example, because im not 100% sure about what you mean?

Comment: YOU CAN do it usually as you are storing normal values to your table using php.

Comment: Sry i think i miss understod your comment i would not like to save the Json into a Table with sub Table like Match id,Team_1, Team_2 etc